# Does unix page out stopped processes?

Tags: unix, signals

If I send a process SIGSTOP by default the process will cease taking clock cycles, however it does not seem to unload itself from real memory.  Does this behavior vary by implementation, or is there a way to force a process to page out? I use BSD Unix(Mac OS).

Comment: Which unix? There's a lot of them these days...

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: No OS will ever do swapping unless it's absolutely necessary. It's slow and bogs the system down.

Comment: Some process which shall remain nameless *cough*Firefox*cough*, take up CPU while in the background and drain my laptops battery.  Since there is no need for them to preform any operations it is best for them to be off entirely.

Comment: Now I'm confused, is this about CPU or memory? Because if it's about CPU then you've already got the solution.

Comment: I understand now, pagging out is implemented as lazy, so while top shows FF as using a large chunk of real memory, it will be recycled only when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't speak about mac os specifically, usually Unix-based OSes won't instantly page out upon SIGSTOP. There are a few reasons for this:

1. Paging out requires I/O bandwidth; using up I/O bandwidth needlessly might actually slow your computer down.
2. Often processes aren't stopped very long; particularly if you're debugging! For all the OS knows you'll resume it before it even finishes paging out.
3. There's no real need to force-page-out. Over time, if there actually is memory pressure, unused data will be paged out, eventually.